# Automatically deploy Win10 using iPXE

Tags: pxe-boot, wim, ipxe

I have iPXE working to boot the Win10 installer. Problem is: after it boots to the installer, I have to  do the following:

```
net use s: \\192.168.250.74\pxe\boot\Win10lts bar /user:foo
s:\sources\setup.exe
```

Then, the installer starts over, and I can install Windows.

I need to have this be an automatic process for when a user in the field needs Windows re-installed. I do not have the patience (and they don't have the time, and in some cases lack the skill / interest) to open a command prompt, run these commands, and then run the installer.

I feel like I should be able to update the `boot.wim` file with DSIM to add some sort of `autoexec.bat` that will do this upon boot.

If I can solve this problem, all I need is an answer file, which I can handle, and we can do re-installs in the field overnight for remote employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top entry in Google for "winpe autorun script" is [Wpeinit and Startnet.cmd: Using WinPE Startup Scripts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wpeinit-and-startnetcmd-using-winpe-startup-scripts)

> You can add customized command-line scripts in Windows PE by using Startnet.cmd. By default, Windows PE includes a Startnet.cmd script located at %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 of your customized Windows PE image.

Comment: Had I searched for that instead of autoexec.bat, I would have found it. Problem was: I didn't know to search for that. Everything is easy to find if you know what to search for.